# Save the form if not complete and come back another time to complete the form

Tags: form, ajax, user-profile, plugin-formbuilder2

I am using the [FormBuilder plugin](https://github.com/roundhouse/FormBuilder-2-Craft-CMS) and I want users to be able to fill in a form. If they abandon the form without completing it or submitting it, I want the form to be saved and when they login and return to the form I want the user to be able to continue where they left off.

I am fairly new to Craft CMS and Twig so I don't know where to start with this or if this is even possible in Craft.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FormBuilder plugin has no option to edit a submitted form. I think the best way is to use a channel in Craft CMS and write your own form. You can find the documentation on how to create/edit entries in frontend here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form.